# On focus of div change background to gray with styled-components

Tags: css, styled-components

I have this div in styled components

```
   const StyledDots = styled.div`
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: solid 1px #d2d2d2;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: relative;
  top: 50px;
  right: 15px;

  ::focus {
    background: black;
  } `
```

I tried to change background color to gray with focus but as you see I'm doing something  wrong and i Dont know what,Any suggestions please?

(Would be better if only 50% of the div will change the color)

Answer (score 1):

to change style onHover, onFocus, ...etc with styled components you need to use this  syntax:

```css
&:focus {
    background: black;
  }
```

for background to be 50% of the height you can use `linear-gradient` to set the background color:

```css
&:focus {
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, black 50%, white 50%);
  }
```